# How to get a text file into an array and search for specific values but being limited to One-Dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays

As the title says, I'm trying to get this [Weather Station Data File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rDy6.png) into an array and be able to search for specific values in the file via a menu system. I built the menu system but have no clue on how to import the file to such an array or series of arrays. The only problem I have is that I am limited to using a one-dimensional array for the data. Neither my textbook nor professor have been of any help. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class VidrioTomas2 {
public static void main(String[] args) 
  throws FileNotFoundException {

  System.out.println("Please give the data titled 'Bellevue College Weather Station Data.txt'.");
  System.out.println("The data must be in the 10 minute data format.");
  Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.print("Please type the file name: ");
  String name = console.nextLine(); //Uses the user input to find the file.
  if (name.equals("Bellevue College Weather Station Data.txt")) { //Needs to type the.txt and in the way the program says it is.
     System.out.println("\nFile name secured. Proceeding to next step.");
     File input = new File(name); //Stores the file into a value that can used in other methods.
  if(input.length() == 67481){
     System.out.println("\nLength of file: " + input.length() + "\nConfirmation of data. Proceeding to next step."); //Used as a confirmation that the file is true and working.
     System.out.println("The following options are available. Please select one of them.");
     System.out.println("1) Peak Wind Speed" 
                       + "\n2) Maximum Temperature" 
                       + "\n3) Humidity and Temperature" 
                       + "\n4) Solar Energy" 
                       + "\n5) End Program");
     Scanner secondConsole = new Scanner (System.in);
     System.out.print("Your selection: ");
     int choice = secondConsole.nextInt();//Uses the user input to start up one of the options.
        switch (choice) {
           case 1:
              System.out.println("Starting Peak Wind Speed Calculation. . .");
              peakWindSpeedCalc(input);
              break;
           case 2:
              System.out.println("Starting Maximum Temperature Calculation. . .");
              maximumTempCalc(input);
              break;
           case 3:
              System.out.println("Starting Humidity and Temperature Calculation. . .");
              humidAndTempCalc(input);
              break;
           case 4:
              System.out.println("Starting Solar Energy Calculation. . .");
              solarEnergyCalc(input);
              break;
           case 5:
              System.out.println("Ending program. . .");
              break;
        }
       } else {
        System.out.println("Inproper file. Ending program. . ."); //Kills if the length is not the same. The file I had had a length of 67481.
        }
  } else {
     System.out.println("\nInproper name or type. Ending program. . ."); //Kills if file name is wrong. Caps sensitive.
  }
} 

public static void peakWindSpeedCalc(File rawData) {
  System.out.println("Placeholder.exe is active. peakWindSpeedCalc is linked correctly.");
}

public static void maximumTempCalc(File rawData) {
  System.out.println("Placeholder.exe is active. maximumTempCalc is linked correctly.");
}

public static void humidAndTempCalc(File rawData) {
  System.out.println("Placeholder.exe is active. humdAndTempCalc is linked correctly.");
}

public static void solarEnergyCalc(File rawData) {
  System.out.println("Placeholder.exe is active. solarEnergyCalc is linked correctly.");
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see a clear problem statement here.  You need to tell us the perceived problem with your code, highlight it, and then maybe also tell us what you have tried so far to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the file object:

```
File input = new File(name);
```

Next, you need to parse it. Judging by your screenshot, the first few lines aren't totally useful, so you could skip them, then use `split()` on the useful lines:

```
String[] firstline = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath()).get(3).split("\\W");
```

Now you have an array with each of the values for the first line. You could set up constants to index into this list, so you could refer to it like `firstline[BAR]`.

If you want to store everything in a single array, then you would index into it like this, for example:

```
data[line * numColumns + col]
```